# jQuery crashing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

When im trying to load a page sometimes its crashing and not loading, My browser is saying its jQuery but thats hosted with Google, If I remove this however everything else seems to work fine, Can anybody see any errors in my code or know where I can go to validate this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
  $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
  $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});

  $('#viewport').carousel('#simplePrevious', '#simpleNext');

  $('.viewer').each(function() {
    $(this).carousel('.viewer #simplePrevious', '.viewer #simpleNext');
  });

  //$('#slider-stage').carousel('#previous', '#next');
  $('#tab-container').easytabs();

  // Dropdown, show more text
  $('.useful-links ul li a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next('p').toggle();
    return false;  
  });
});
```

---

If i comment this out

```
//$('.viewer').each(function() {
//    $(this).carousel('.viewer #simplePrevious', '.viewer #simpleNext');
//});
```

Everything works fine, Some pages dont actually have a carousel viewer on there, could this be the problem, should i check to see if the element exists first?

Comment: Are all the jQuery plugins loading correctly?

Comment: Open the javascritp console in FF or Chrome and see the actual javascript error that is happening, you can paste it here also so we can help.

Comment: Thats my only problem, Ive tried the console in firebug only the page causes my browser to crash, only if i remove the above it works...

Comment: Are you having multiple elements with ids #simplePrevious and #simpleNext? Id should be unique in the entire page.

Comment: If there are no `.viewer` elements on the page it should just skip that part and shouldn't be a problem. Which browsers does it crash for?

Comment: Define crash ? does windows need to close it or does the page just not render ?

Comment: The browser needs to close...